# Cocos2d V3 and Spritebuilder - Timeline animation not running subsequent times

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I have a CCB file with a timeline animation in it. I load the file like this.

```
CCSprite *spriteAnimation = (CCSprite*)[CCBReader load:@"MyGreatAnimation"];
spriteAnimation.paused = TRUE;
```

At some point later, I add it to the scene and run the animation

```
[MyScene addChild:spriteAnimation];
CCAnimationManager* animationManager = _deletionAnimaion.userObject;
[animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"Default Timeline"];
```

This is great. My animation runs. I then remove `spriteAnimation` from the scene until I need it again.

```
[spriteAnimation removeFromParent];
```

.

## **The problem**

I can't figure out how to get the animation to run the next time I add it to the scene.

I've tried:

```
[animationManager jumpToSequenceNamed:@"Default Timeline" time:0];
```

And also..

```
[animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"Default Timeline"];
```

But the animation doesn't seem to run. If at this point I call:

```
spriteAnimation.userObject.runningSequenceName
```

to see the running sequence, it returns `NULL`.

.

## **My Question**

How do I arbitrarily run a timeline animation repeatedly?

To be clear, I'm not asking about looping the animation. I want to start it from frame 1 whenever I need.

Comment: Hold onto the spriteAnimation in a retained property?

Answer (score 0):

If you need it repeatedly, you shouldn't remove it from the scene:

```
[spriteAnimation removeFromParent];
```

Instead, just make the animation invisible for the time being:

```
spriteAnimation.visible = NO;
```

Later just make it visible again.

After all when you remove a node it is gone from the scene hierarchy unless you addChild: it back in which I can't see in your code above.

Comment: Sorry, left out the addChild: form my sample code above. I was using addChilde: and it didn't work. I also tried setting visible=no, and that did't work either. What eventually worked was setting opacity to 0 and setting position of screen (so it doesn't get included in the draw). Then when I want it again, I just moved it into position and set opacity to 1. I wonder if the act of removing it from i's parent clears the animations?